# How to put 2 sub-figures side by side inside an mdframed example default frame?

Tags: subcaption, mdframed

Got an error when tried to put 2 sub-figures side by side inside an mdframed  example default frame. I tried to use \captionof and also subfigure domain.
Below is my main code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{exampledefault}{linewidth=2pt}
\newtheorem{my_definition}{DEFINITION}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[style=exampledefault]
\begin{my_definition}\textbf{[My Definition]:}\label{mine}
Let us see the figure below:

\begin{center}

\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\includestandalone[width=.4\linewidth]{simple_figure}
\captionof{A subfigure}
\label{fig:sub1}
\end{center}
\end{subfigure}%

\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\includestandalone[width=.4\linewidth]{simple_figure}
\captionof{A subfigure}
\label{fig:sub2}
\end{center}
\end{subfigure}

\captionof{A figure with two subfigures}
\label{fig:test}
\end{center}

\end{my_definition}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

And below is my standalone Tikz figure code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [line width=1](-2.5,-2) rectangle (2.5,2) (2.5,2) node [above] {$U$};
\draw [line width=1] (-.5,0) circle (1) (-.5,1) node [above] {$A$} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And finally below is my error:
! Package caption Error: \setcaptionsubtype outside float.
I appreciate your support in advance!

Comment: Try dding `\captionsetup{type=figure}` before using a subfigure, but it will definitely work for a minipage and `\captionof{subfigure}{...}`.  A subfigure is basically a minipage with captions.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The `subfigure` environments works only in `figure` (float) environment.
- Correct syntax for the `\captionof` is in your case `\captionof{figure}{<caption text>}`
- Try to use the `subfloat` environment defined in the `subfig` package instead it:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig} % <---
\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{exampledefault}{linewidth=2pt}
\newtheorem{my_definition}{DEFINITION}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[style=exampledefault]
\begin{my_definition}
\textbf{[My Definition]:}\label{mine}
Let us see the figure below:

\begin{center}
\captionsetup{type=figure} % <---
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\subfloat[Subfigure A]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}}
%\includestandalone[width=\linewidth]{simple_figure}
\label{fig:sub1}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\subfloat[Subfigure B]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}}
%\includestandalone[width=\linewidth]{simple_figure}
\label{fig:sub2}
\end{minipage}

\captionof{figure}{A figure with two sub figures}
\label{fig:test}
\end{center}

\end{my_definition}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

- In above MWE is used example images contained in `graphicx` package. Proposed solution should work with your images included as `standalone` images

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your great supportive answer!